# Fontswesomefx icons change to a rectangle when the font size is specified

Tags: css, javafx-8, font-awesome, fxml

I'm using fontawesomefx in the javafx project.
I'm able to display the icons in the application but when I change the font size the images show as rectangle.
What am i doing wrong ?
When add I the below css , the fonts change to rectangles.

```
.root {
  -fx-font-size: 15.0px; 
 }
```

Here's the main class

```
package com.test.fontawesome.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FontTest.fxml"));
        // ToolBar toolBar = loader.load();
        BorderPane root = loader.load();
        // root.setTop(toolBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/font_awesome.css");
        primaryStage.setTitle("Font Awesome with JavaFX");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

FXML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIconView?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
    prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <ToolBar prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="600.0"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <Button>
                    <graphic>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView glyphName="WINDOW_MINIMIZE">
                        </MaterialDesignIconView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <graphic>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView glyphName="APPLE">
                        </MaterialDesignIconView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <graphic>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView glyphName="ARCHIVE">
                        </MaterialDesignIconView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
            </items>
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: What OS and Java version are you using? I've been having similar problems on Linux, but not on windows. Haven't figured out why it happens or how to solve them yet.

Comment: Its windows 7 and jdk1.8.0_66. Were you able to change the font size in windows ?

Comment: Is't there an own pseudo class? I found -glyph-size: 6em;

Comment: I'm doing this  `.root {
  -fx-font-size: 15.0px; 
 }`  to change the font of the text across the application. But this is changing the fontawesome icons behavior as specified the question.

Comment: When I add this `.glyph-icon{
 -fx-font-family:"Material Design Icons";
}` to my css it works fine.  Not sure if this is an elegant way of doing it

Comment: I also have the same problem, Did you found any solution?

Comment: @James_D do you see this?

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana  As mentioned in one of my comments here , adding   .glyph-icon{ -fx-font-family:"Material Design Icons"; } to the css fixed it

Comment: It worked for me `.glyph-icon { -glyph-size: 40; }`, somehow `.glyph-icon{ -fx-font-size: 15.0px; }` is not working because inline css form somewhere is overriding property